# Bitnami wordpress website gives the error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when been accessed via the web

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services

The website https://www.myhomeetal.com has been online for over 5 months now but can no longer be accessed via the url.Pinging the ip return request timed out and using the url gives the error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. its currently  deployed on an aws ec2 linux machine and l can ssh into the machine. The status of apache,mysql shows running and l cant see any error log in the wordpress directory. please any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is problem with domain route, not site. Do You change any DNS records or settings into the AWS control panel ?

Comment: @NikPashchuk...The domain name was registered by a branch of the company in india and mapped to the aws instance. all l did was give them the ip address.

Comment: that is Your problem, in changing IP, current `nslookup` test gives not answer. `Non-authoritative answer: *** Can't find myhomeetal.com: No answer` , try to turn back previous settings, route problem, browser don't know where to point(to which server) user.

Comment: @NikPashchuk ..thanks boss..you were absolutely right. the ip that was mapped to the domain name was different from that on ec2. l cant thank u enough for your time..thanks

Comment: Glad to solve Your problem, check question as solved if possible and if You don't have other troubles.

Answer (score 0):

you need LiteSpeed configuration there may be insufficient memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).